# 403 error after installing OpenCart

Tags: installation, opencart, chmod, http-status-code-403

I have recently uploaded **OpenCart 2.0** on my web hosting and after upload I saw this message

> "Error 403 - Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this page
>   or directory listing on the server"

This is my URL `"www.#####.com/ecommerce"`

I have set **777 CHMOD** to all folders.
But still the message still displays.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Permission problem ,please follow the bellow permission -

Directory - 755 permission

Files - 644 permission

Comment: `755` and `644` as you advise is even more restrictive than `777` which the OP has already set and tried. Why do you think this should help?

Comment: Its because of server configuration (for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you setting it up with? I'm using nginx.

A couple of things you can try to fix the issue (I had this too)

- Check your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/[your site conf]` file to ensure that you have the site reading `*.php` files. Once I fixed this, I stopped getting the `403` errors.

> ```
> # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
> index index.html index.php;
> ```

- Ensure that you followed the opencart install.txt file, copying over the `upload` folder contents to the web server folder (Mine is `/var/www/html/`)
- If using nginx, use this tutorial to get php support: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx